# Efficient way to check if a graph node's children were visited during traversal

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal

I have a generic traversal algorithm for graphs:

```
Traversal (container) {
    while (container is not empty ){
        visit container.pop()
        push new nodes
    }
}
```

and I want to make a time-efficient "child head count" for nodes that sets a flag for nodes whenever all their children have been visited:

```
Traversal (container) {
    while (container is not empty ){
        visit container.pop()
        push new nodes
        set close flag on parent nodes if last child to be visited
    }
}
```

The best ways that i could think of was to have pointers to "visited" booleans of the node's children and just "and" them up as such:

```
node1 -> [node2(true), node5(false), node7(true)]

node1.all_children_visited() = false
```

Or iterate through the parents whenever I visit the node for the first time:

```
Traversal (container) {
    while (container is not empty ){
        visit container.pop()
        push new nodes
        if first visit {
            for each parent {
                increase count
                if count(parent) = number of children {close(parent)}
            }
            if count(this) = number of children {close(this)}
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this with lower than O(n) complexity?

Comment: Do you want $o(n)$ per query `if last child` or for the whole traversal?

Comment: What does `close parent nodes if last child`?  What does it mean to `close` a node?  The parent nodes of what?  What does `if last child` mean?  Also, what does "child head count" mean?  Can you edit your question to explain this more clearly?

Comment: It looks like you're writing a [depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_first_search). Would you like help?

Comment: The data structure you seem to be using appears to force all $\Omega(n)$ nodes to be visited to ensure that all of them are counted.  If counting is important, then you could augment the data structure with a counter that is incremented when new a node is added and decremented when a node is removed.

Comment: It's not DFS. It's a generic traversal. Depending on the container, you can make it work as any traversal you want. And closing a node means setting a flag that tells the traversal that all the child nodes of that node have been visited.

Comment: So you're asking if you can visit $n$ nodes in less than $n$ time?

Comment: No. I'm asking if I can know if I visited all the node's children in less than n time.

Answer (score 2):

If you can afford more memory, add a field to each node's data containing a count of already visited children. Assuming that you know the number of children, if you update this field each time you visit a child, you will know when all children have been visited.

Comment: Problem is whenever I do that I also have to update it for each other parent, which in turn turns into O(n)

Comment: The amortized complexity is still $O(1)$ per node.

Comment: It's O(E) per node.

Comment: Each edge is accessed $O(1)$ times, so at worst its amortized $O(1)$ per edge.

Comment: Which makes it O(Edge) if you count searching for a specific node count as O(1)

Comment: The worst case complexity is actually only $O(V)$, but amortized it's just $O(1)$.

Comment: It's not constant cost. You are underestimating the cost of |E|. Every graph search algorithm is analyzed in function of |V| and |E| for a reason.

Comment: I'm talking about the additional cost, which is $O(1)$ amortized per node, or $O(V)$ in total. Perhaps I got something wrong, and then it would be $O(V+E)$ in total.